# Datepicker refresh is not working?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datepicker

I am working on asp.net mvc application, After submitting selected date to the database , I want to refresh datepicker , I am able to refresh datepicker only pageload. I dont want to refresh whole page,
I am having input field on popup (datepicker also). On submit button i am using ajax , so the whole page is not refreshed and datepicker holds previous selection, So how can i refresh datepicker.

This is jquery code i am using after ajax

```
function saveandContinue() {
    if (!validateManageRequestmodel())
        return;
    else
        $("#showerrormsg").hide();

    var model = getManageRequestmodel();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AddManageRequest",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: $.toJSON(model),
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            if (result.Status == "ERROR") {
                showErrorMessage('showerrormsg', result.Result);
            }
            else if (result.Status == "OK") {
                showSuccessMessage('showerrormsg', 'Record saved successfully.');
                    **$(".datepicker").datepicker("refresh");**
                iIncrease++;
                if (gsaveParameter === 'add')
                    resetManageRequest();
                else if (gsaveParameter === 'edit') {
                    if (iIncrease < selectedIDs.length)
                        GetDataForEdit(selectedIDs[iIncrease]);
                    else {
                        $('#manageRequestModal').modal('hide');
                        onActionRefreshGrid();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            debugger;
            showErrorMessage('showerrormsg', error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo link: 1](http://codepen.io/alexgill/pen/yOQrwV) 
[Demo link: 2](http://jsfiddle.net/archinmodi/403w2a0v)

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Comment: Thanks . but why refresh is not working like--$('.datepicker').datepicker('refresh');

Comment: your above code is refresh  the datepicker thats good,but also here i want to disable past date in input box and disable future date in another input box, so disabling past and future date is not working, i also used your demo link:2

Comment: show me your datepicker past and future disble code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the page is already loaded **`$(".datepicker").datepicker("refresh");`** will not reflect the changes.

Better if you could create a function which can used whenever required

```
function InitializeDate() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but not working,  Inside resetManageRequest() function i am refreshing the datepicker but not working , look here my code -$('#txtdatereceiving').datepicker('refresh');
        $('#txtTATdate').datepicker('refresh');

Comment: set **async:false** inside your $.ajax @Sudhakarsingh